# Hide Lanscape mode in Android phone in NativeScript Angular

Tags: nativescript

Hide Lanscape mode in Android phone in NativeScript Angular

1.Allow both orientations in  Android tablet

2.Restrict Landscape and allow only portriat version in phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lockOrientation(orientation) {
    const activity = app.android.startActivity;
    switch (orientation) {
        case 'unlocked':
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
            break;

        case 'portrait-primary':
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            break;

        case 'portrait-secondary':
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            break;

        case 'landscape-primary':
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            break;

        case 'landscape-secondary':
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            break;

        case 'portrait':
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            break;

        case 'landscape':
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            break;

        default:
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            break;
    }
```

just checking and calling the below method is working for me

```
        if (app.android && device.deviceType === 'Phone') {
            this.lockOrientation('portrait');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `deviceType` from [platforms](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/platform) to know which device type the app is running. If it's `Tablet` then use nativescript orientation plugin to lock the orientation to portrait.

Comment: Nativescript orientation plugin? is that plugin available? can you share the code snippet?

Comment: Use the pro version if you are worried about long term support. I think the last version still works - https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-orientation more over this particular plugin is few lines of code, you can always directly use the native code if you know what you are looking at.